# PHP string encode

Tags: php, codeigniter, encoding

I have some site written on php5 using most ancient CodeIgniter version.
I have config:

```
$config['charset'] = 'windows-1251';
```

At some place, I have 2 string values.

1. `$this->uri->segment(2)`
2. `"{shortname}" . ".html"`

I want compare them, and do something if they are equals.
But I get into hell...

Now, I have some code in some view:

```
<?=(strcmp($this->uri->segment(2), "{shortname}" . ".html") == 0) ?
        'test' :
        'notest' ?><br/>
<?=mb_detect_encoding($this->uri->segment(2))?><br/>
<?=mb_detect_encoding("{shortname}" . ".html")?><br/>
<?=base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding($this->uri->segment(2), 'UTF-8'))?><br/>
<?=base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding("{shortname}" . ".html", 'UTF-8'))?><br/>
<?=$this->uri->segment(2)?><br/>
<?="{shortname}" . ".html"?><br/>
```

As a result I have:

```
notest
ASCII
ASCII
cml6b2dyYWZpamEtdGlyYXpoaXJvdmFuaWUuaHRtbA==
e3Nob3J0bmFtZX0uaHRtbA==
rizografija-tirazhirovanie.html
rizografija-tirazhirovanie.html
```

How I need encode/decode/compare for it will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base64_decode("e3Nob3J0bmFtZX0uaHRtbA==")` = `{shortname}.html`

Your `{shortname}` placeholder is not replaced.
I'm not use CodeIgniter, but maybe you like to use `{$shortname}` ? (inserts `$shortname` variable value)

Example:

```
echo strcmp($this->uri->segment(2), "$shortname.html") == 0) ? 'test' : 'notest';
```

Comment: Yes! It is the reason. It replaced only if I use it directly: <?={shortname}?>. But if I pass it as an argument, it not replacing... I put the condition in controller. Thank you very much!